# How To Consistently Get A ScrollView To Scroll To The Bottom In SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have seen numerous posts about similar issues, where either the scrolling to the bottom of a ScrollView is inaccurate and or doesn't always work correctly.

I am building a simple chat app and am trying to the get the scrollview to always scroll to the bottom when a message is received.

I have tried using different views with the .id() property as well as 'invisible markers'. None of these are consistent. So Im wondering if anyone has any ideas.

```
struct ChatView: View {
  
  @ObservedObject
  var viewModel = ChatModel()
  
  enum FocusedData: Int, Hashable {
    case message
  }
  
  @FocusState
  private var focusedField: FocusedData?
  
  let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
  
  @Namespace var topAnchorID
  @Namespace var bottomAnchorID
  
  @ObservedObject
  var keyboardObserver = KeyboardObserver()
  
  @State
  private var userMessage = ""
  
  @State
  var isUsingKeyboard = false
  
  var body: some View {
    
    ScrollViewReader{ proxy in
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ScrollView() {
          Color.red.frame(height: 1).id(topAnchorID)
          LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(viewModel.messageHistory, id: \.identifier) { data in
              MessageView(data: data).id(data.identifier)
            }
          }.id(UUID())
          Color.red.frame(height: 1).id(bottomAnchorID)
        }.scrollDismissesKeyboard(.immediately)
          .onChange(of: userMessage, perform: {_ in
            guard !userMessage.isEmpty else { return }
            proxy.scrollTo(bottomAnchorID)
          })
          .onReceive(viewModel.$messageHistory.throttle(for: 0.2, scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: true), perform: { history in
            withAnimation {
              // This doesn't seem to work correctly.
              proxy.scrollTo(bottomAnchorID)
            }
            
          })
          .onChange(of: keyboardObserver.keyboardState, perform: { state in
            handleKeyboardState(state, for: proxy)
          })
          .onAppear() {
            focusedField = FocusedData(rawValue: 0)
          }
        TextInputView().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have an MRE but there are a few glaring issues that would result in inconsistent results such as using `@ObservedObject` to initialize. using `onChange` instead of `task(id:)`